# Are there any issues with having having the main data in an object's state?

Tags: object-oriented, python

```
class DataFrameAnnotation:

  def __init__(self, df: pd.DataFrame):
    self.df = df

  def transformation_1(self):
    self.df + 1 

  def transformation_2(self):
    self.df + 1 

  def main(self):
    self.transformation_1()
    self.transformation_2()
    ....
    return self.df
```

My question is if there are any issues keeping a large dataframe in an object's state like the above compared to passing the dataframe around as a parameter:

```
   def main(self, df):
        df = self.transformation_1(df)
        df = self.transformation_2(df)
        ....
        return df
```

Comment: The flyweight pattern comes to mind for consideration: https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/flyweight

Answer (score 2):

Since the dataframe isn't actually being copied but only referenced, you don't have an inefficiency issue. But, you do have a coupling issue depending on the design of your system.

If the class holding the dataframe object is the responsible entity, it's a plausible choice. However, if you have more than one object that holds a reference to this object, you have a tight coupling between this objects (along the lines; how object A can track changes of the shared object with manipulations that object B invoked).

In order to reduce this coupling you can either ask yourself if there's a distinction between object A to B (and if they really must be separated by design), or if object B can remove its' ownership of the object as a member and expose a well-defined API (with the object as parameter) instead.

Either way, you should strive for that behavior since a two (or more) separated classes manipulating the same data object via an ill-defined API can be hard to maintain in the long run.

Answer (score 0):

`DataFrameAnnotation` has no state besides that pandas dataframe.
Since `self.df` seems public `DataFrameAnnotation` is not encapsulating operations on the dataframe.
I see no reason for that class to exist. Why are the `transformation_` methods not module level functions?

p.s: that code is not valid python

Comment: that's not the only attribute for the class, so there is state besides the df. and also I really don't like module level functions. I know it's acceptable in python (maybe even recommended), but I prefer them to be static methods in a class where possible. I find it more readable instead of opening a file with various functions in it.